# Crypto.Signature missing when Travis-ci builds pycrypto

Tags: travis-ci, pycrypto

I have a software library that uses pycrypto and it works perfectly.
The project is on github (https://github.com/rohe/pyjwkest/).
Yesterday I tried to add Travis-ci integration to my github project.

But so far the CI status has been 'failed' all the time.

And it fails on:
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5

with the error
ImportError: No module named Signature

No error is reported when building pycrypto/Crypto so what gives ?